# Is it safe to give Google details to 3rd party apps like Reeder

Tags: security, google

I am just wondering that, is it safe to use your primary google account details to sign in into 3rd party apps like [reeder](http://reederapp.com/)?

If it is safe then how exactly that authentication works. I am sure they are not using OpenID because I checked the applications that I gave access to and this app was not listed there.

Answer (score 1):

[Authentication and Authorization for Google APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/GettingStarted.html) has the basics of their mechanism.
It seems, you now need to do a [two-factor authentication](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/advanced-sign-in-security-for-your.html) on reeder.

Here is a recent metafilter thread on [trusting 3rd-party apps with login info](http://ask.metafilter.com/188413/Can-I-trust-3rdparty-apps-with-login-info).

Answer (score 1):

If you're typing your password into a 3rd party application/website you have to trust them with it.. OpenID is when you log in to a third-party site via a redirect to Google (you're  entering the password only into Google's web-page).

Perhaps you can create another Google Account and import your feeds into it.

Comment: I am trusting them but I am just curious to know how is that working. I am sure they are not using OAuth either because according to the OAuth docs I am not getting asked by Google to approve access to the application.